# Extract entity strings from an Outlook365 item

Tags: office365-apps

```
            // Global variables
            var _Item;
            var _MyEntities;

            // The initialize function is required for all apps.
            Office.initialize = function (reason) {
                var _mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
                // Obtains the current item.
                Item = _mailbox.item;
                // Reads all instances of supported entities from the subject
                // and body of the current item.
                MyEntities = _Item.getEntities();

                // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
                $(document).ready(function () {
                // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
                });
            }

            // Gets instances of the Address entity on the item.
            function myGetAddresses()
            {
                var htmlText = "";

                // Gets an array of postal addresses. Each address is a string.
                var addressesArray = _MyEntities.addresses;
                for (var i = 0; i < addressesArray.length; i++)
                {
                    htmlText += "Address : <span>" + addressesArray[i] + "</span><br/>";
                }

                document.getElementById("entities_box").innerHTML = htmlText;
            }
```

I am using above code to access email address, but I am not able to see any result in entities_box div.

Please suggest how can I can get to,cc and from email address from it.

Answer (score 0):

entities are only available if the message itself has entities extracted (eg "123 Main st, New York, New York 10001"). I would start debugging by first checking if the address has actually been detected (does the Bing Maps app activate on that message? did you leave it enabled?). Then, call json.stringify and see what item.getEntities() actually returns. Here's an article on how to extract entities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161071(v=office.15).aspx